# How to filter nested array in typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, typescript, filter

I have a JSON as below

```
{
  "Header": {
    "Time": "2020-06-09T07:03:20-07:00",
    "ReportName": "JournalReport",
    "StartPeriod": "2020-06-09",
    "EndPeriod": "2020-06-09",
    "Currency": "USD",
    "Option": [
      {
        "Name": "NoReportData",
        "Value": "false"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Columns": {
    "Column": [
      {
        "ColTitle": "Date",
        "ColType": "Date",
        "MetaData": [
          {
            "Name": "ColKey",
            "Value": "tx_date"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ColTitle": "Transaction Type",
        "ColType": "String",
        "MetaData": [
          {
            "Name": "ColKey",
            "Value": "txn_type"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ColTitle": "Num",
        "ColType": "String",
        "MetaData": [
          {
            "Name": "ColKey",
            "Value": "doc_num"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ColTitle": "Name",
        "ColType": "String",
        "MetaData": [
          {
            "Name": "ColKey",
            "Value": "name"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ColTitle": "Memo/Description",
        "ColType": "String",
        "MetaData": [
          {
            "Name": "ColKey",
            "Value": "memo"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ColTitle": "Account",
        "ColType": "String",
        "MetaData": [
          {
            "Name": "ColKey",
            "Value": "account_name"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ColTitle": "Debit",
        "ColType": "Money",
        "MetaData": [
          {
            "Name": "ColKey",
            "Value": "debt_home_amt"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ColTitle": "Credit",
        "ColType": "Money",
        "MetaData": [
          {
            "Name": "ColKey",
            "Value": "credit_home_amt"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "Rows": {
    "Row": [
      {
        "ColData": [
          {
            "value": "0-00-00"
          },
          {
            "value": "",
            "id": "559"
          },
          {
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "value": "",
            "id": ""
          },
          {
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "value": "California Department of Tax and Fee Administration Payable",
            "id": "678"
          },
          {
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "value": "1.25"
          }
        ],
        "type": "Data"
      },
      {
        "ColData": [
          {
            "value": "0-00-00"
          },
          {
            "value": "",
            "id": "559"
          },
          {
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "value": "",
            "id": ""
          },
          {
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "value": "California Department of Tax and Fee Administration Payable",
            "id": "678"
          },
          {
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "value": ".10"
          }
        ],
        "type": "Data"
      },
      {
        "Summary": {
          "ColData": [
            {
              "value": ""
            },
            {
              "value": ""
            },
            {
              "value": ""
            },
            {
              "value": ""
            },
            {
              "value": ""
            },
            {
              "value": ""
            },
            {
              "value": "31.75"
            },
            {
              "value": "31.75"
            }
          ]
        },
        "type": "Section"
      },
      {
        "ColData": [
          {
            "value": "0-00-00"
          },
          {
            "value": "",
            "id": "567"
          },
          {
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "value": "",
            "id": ""
          },
          {
            "value": ""
          },
          {
            "value": "Accounts Payable (A/P)",
            "id": "676"
          },
          {
            "value": "232.00"
          },
          {
            "value": ""
          }
        ],
        "type": "Data"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to filter this array which matches `Rows.Row[someindex].ColData[1].id == 567`. Here `id` should match with `second` object of  ColData array.

But after filtering i don't want to skip the records from resulting array those have `Summary` as `Rows.Row[someindex].Summary`. Summary records should be included in resulting array.

I have tried below code but it does not work because In `Row.Row` array `Summary` can be there instead of `ColData` at some indexs & also i want include `Summary` records in resulting array even if i have found the desired object.

```
function getResult(filterbY, objList) {
  return objList.Rows.Row.filter(function(obj) {
   return obj.ColData.some(function(item){
     return item.id == filterbY;
   });
 });
}
```

Please help with the same ?

Comment: Can you provide expected output of the getResult function?

Answer (score 0):

you need to include your summary in your filter function then,

```
function getResult(filterbY, objList) {
  return objList.Rows.Row.filter(function(obj) {
   if(obj.Summary){return true;}
   return obj.ColData.some(function(item){
     return item.id == filterbY;
   });
 });
}
```

Comment: you are using typescript right ? `x ?? y` basically means `x != null ? x : y;`

Comment: it was introduced with typescript 3.7, [read more](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#nullish-coalescing)

Comment: but i want to include all summary objects in resulting array whether id is matched or not. So only coldata objects are filtered rest is included.

Comment: Thanks this seems better but can i get json structure as original json passed as of now headers,column section is skipped out of it. How can i return restructured json ?

Comment: Because you are returning filtered rows, you need to apply the filter on the object of you want to get the object result, so instead of objList.Rows.row.filter, it should be objList.filter